# Reflectively calling function and using default parameters

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Given the following function

```
fun function(x: Int = 12) {
    println("x = $x")
}
```

How can I using reflection invoke it without specifying `x` (or somehow using default value, *not* hard coding it)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`callBy`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/call-by.html), which respects the default values:

```
::function.callBy(emptyMap()) // is just function()
```

Things will be messy if you have many parameters without default values:

```
fun foo(a: Int, b: String = "") {}
val ref = ::foo
val params = ref.parameters
ref.callBy(mapOf(params[0] to 1))  // is just foo(1)
```

It will be even more boring if your function is a member function of a non-object type, or it's extension function, or it's an extension function to a type as a member function of a (other) non-object type.

I wrote a convenient method to reduce boilerplate:

```
fun <R> KFunction<R>.callNamed(params: Map<String, Any?>, self: Any? = null, extSelf: Any? = null): R {
    val map = params.entries.mapTo(ArrayList()) { entry ->
        parameters.find { name == entry.key }!! to entry.value
    }
    if (self != null) map += instanceParameter!! to self
    if (extSelf != null) map += extensionReceiverParameter!! to extSelf
    return callBy(map.toMap())
}
```

Usage:

```
fun String.foo(a: Int, b: String = "") {}
fun foo(a: Int, b: String = "") {}
class Foo {
    fun bar(a: Int, b: String = "") {}
    fun String.baz(a: Int, b: String = "") {}
}

::foo.callNamed(mapOf("a" to 0))
String::foo.callNamed(mapOf("a" to 0), extSelf = "")
Foo::bar.callNamed(mapOf("a" to 0), Foo())
// function reference don't work on member extension functions
Foo::class.declaredFunctions.find { it.name == "baz" }!!.callNamed(mapOf("a" to 0), Foo(), "")
```